# AJAX Https request showing CORS error. (From local server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following is the code I tested.
**Code:**

```js
$.ajax({
  url : 'https://github.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/blob/master/states-and-districts.json',
  type : 'GET',
  datatype : 'json',
  header: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://github.com'
  }
  .done(function(response)){
    data = JSON.parse(response);
    loadlog(data);
  }
});
```

Following is the error I am receiving when running the above code.
**Error:**

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://github.com/somelink/data.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' \ has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I have looked into many resources, also. 
[Resource #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093053/access-control-request-headers-is-added-to-header-in-ajax-request-with-jquery) 
[Resource #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/why-does-my-http-localhost-cors-origin-not-work)

Can somebody explain the reason for the above error, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS issue in Jquery with GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700528/cors-issue-in-jquery-with-get-method)

Answer (score 2):

Go to that url and click on Raw button and use the resulting `raw.githubusercontent.com` url which is CORS enabled

```js
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/master/states-and-districts.json')
.then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```